# XSL key, create a key out of ill-formated data

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML-file and want to count how many items are attached to each callNumber - a quite easy task if my data had been wellformatted :-(

Problem is I want to create a key for either

a) the whole callNumber if it doesn't contain a space 
or

b) the part before space if there are spaces in callNumber
so, '12' should be included in the same key as '12 34'

Solutions I have rejected so far:

substring - doesn't work as the length of Callnumber varies

substring before space - doesn't work as some callNumbers doesn't contain a space.

Is this at all possible, or is my data too weird?
I can only use XSL 1.0, without extensions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="countitempercall.xsl"?>
    <report>
        <catalog>
            <call>
                <callNumber>12</callNumber>
                <item>
                    <itemID>305810</itemID>
                </item>
            </call>
        </catalog>
        <catalog>
            <call>
                <callNumber>12 34</callNumber>
                <item>
                    <itemID>305811</itemID>
                </item>
            </call>
        </catalog>
        <catalog>
            <call>
                <callNumber>567A89</callNumber>
                <item>
                    <itemID>305812</itemID>
                </item>
            </call>
        </catalog>
        <catalog>
            <call>
                <callNumber>567A89 Abc</callNumber>
                <item>
                    <itemID>305813</itemID>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <itemID>305814</itemID>
                </item>
            </call>
        </catalog>
    </report>
```

My stylesheet so far

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="shelf" match="call" use="callNumber"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <callNumberUsage>

        <xsl:for-each select="//call[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('shelf', callNumber)[1])]">

        <xsl:sort select="callNumber"/>

            <callNumberline>
                <callNumber><xsl:value-of select="callNumber"/></callNumber>
                <numberOfItems><xsl:value-of select="count(key('shelf', callNumber)/item)"/></numberOfItems>
            </callNumberline>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </callNumberUsage>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring-before` in combination with a `concat` to add a space at the end of the `callNumber`

```
<xsl:key name="shelf" match="call" use="substring-before(concat(callNumber, ' '), ' ')"/>
```

In the case where the call number has a space, this second space won't affect it. In the case where it doesn't have a space, you will end up getting the whole number, as required.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="shelf" match="call" use="substring-before(concat(callNumber, ' '), ' ')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <callNumberUsage>

        <xsl:for-each select="//call[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('shelf', substring-before(concat(callNumber, ' '), ' '))[1])]">

        <xsl:sort select="callNumber"/>

            <callNumberline>
                <callNumber><xsl:value-of select="callNumber"/></callNumber>
                <numberOfItems><xsl:value-of select="count(key('shelf', substring-before(concat(callNumber, ' '), ' '))/item)"/></numberOfItems>
            </callNumberline>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </callNumberUsage>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Once more: I'm impressed on how one can do even impossible things with XSL